# Geometric multiplicity of eigenvalues of blocks matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose you have diagonal-blocks matrix, and you can compute the eigenvalues of all the blocks, and their geometric multeplicty.

1. Is it true that the eigenvalues of the matrix are the eigenvalues of the blocks?
2. Is their geometric multeplicity is the same as in the blocks? Even if you find the same eigv in different blocks?

And how questions 1) and 2) change if the matrix is not diagonal-blocks but triangular-blocks?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: With block-diagonal matrices, you can get both geometric and algebraic multiplicities by just adding up the multiplicities from each block. With block-triangular matrices, this only works for the algebraic multiplicities.

Comment: I think that you might be able to work this out for yourself for block-diagonal matrices. Suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of, say, the first block. Can you construct a vector that’s an eigenvector of the block matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$?